# Pretrained model for spectrogram images

Tags: model-selection, transfer-learning

I'm working on a sound classification problem. For that, I'm converting the audio signals into spectrogram images and using transfer learning to classify them. Currently I'm using pretrained models like AlexNet, Mobilenet, Xception etc which were trained on the ImageNet dataset. These models are primarily trained for different object recognition and producing decent result in classifying spectrograms. Although I think that a model trained on a large spectrogram dataset will produce better results. Is there any such model available?